# Finding the date/time a file was first added to a Git repository

Tags: git

Is there a simple [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) command to determine the "creation date" of a file in a repository, i.e. the date it was first added?

It would be best if it can determine this even through file renames/moves. I'd like it to be a computer-readable one-line output; it may be that I haven't figured out the correct `git log <fname>` options to do this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`git log --follow --format=%ad --date default <FILE> | tail -1`

With this command you can out all date about this file and extract the last

The option `%ad` shows the date in the format specified by the --date setting, one of `relative`, `local`, `iso`, `iso-strict`, `rfc`, `short`,  `raw`, `human`, `unix`, `format:<strftime-string>`, `default`.

Comment: You'll also need `--follow` to follow the log through renames as the OP asked. Also good practice to add `--` before the filename just in case it clashes with an option or ref name.

Comment: Since I was planning on calling `git` from Python, I was hoping for a command that doesn't require piping. I suppose I can just get the final line with Python, though. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: @Seth: you could use `subprocess.Popen` and `communicate()` to read stdout into a string. Split the string on \n into a list, then get element -1.  Check out http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: @Steve Folly: I meant that I knew how to use subprocess and `some_string.split('\n')[-1]`, but I was asking for thoughts on getting Git to return only the first log entry.

Comment: Actually, since git leaves a trailing newline, you have to do [-2].

Comment: It is better to use **reverse** in this solution, i.e.
    `git log --follow --format=%aD --reverse -- <fname> | head -1`
(so, you don't need to read the all lines in Python, just the first one)

Comment: @ruvim Using `--reverse` / `head` gives different - and incorrect - results for some files. `tail` just works.

Comment: What is the difference between author date & comitter date (`%aD` vs `%ct`)?

Comment: git has a `--no-pager` options, so you can leave off the `| tail -1` (which also makes it easier to work with xargs)

Comment: @danger89: I don't know about all the cases, but let me give you an example: in case you overwrite your initial commit, `%aD` will show you initial commit date despite the overwrite (the most initial date possible), while `%cD` will show you a new date (so it kinda respects overwrites). Just faced this little nuance myself, sorry for necroing

Answer (score 55):

The native solution:

```
git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aD -1 -- <fname>
```

It gives the **last** "creation date" of a file in a repository, and does it regardless of file renames/moves.

`-1` is synonym to `--max-count=1` and it limits the number of commits to output (to be not more than one in our case).

This limit is needed since a file can be added more than once. For example, it can be added, then removed, then added again. In such case `--diff-filter=A` will produce several lines for this file.

To get the **first** creation date in the first line we should use `--reverse` option without limitation (since [limit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting) is applied before ordering).

```
git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aI --reverse -- <fname> | head -1
```

`%aI` [gives](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emaIem) author date in the strict [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (e.g. `2009-06-03T07:08:51-07:00`).

But this command doesn't work properly due to the known bug in Git (see "[--follow is ignored when used with --reverse](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg212266.html)" conversation in git maillist). So, we are forced to use some work around for awhile to get the **first** creation date. E.g.:

```
git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aI -- <fname> | tail -1
```

Comment: This is a faster way of find the date than the solution by shingara, as well as being cleaner

Comment: What does the `-1` do here? Can a file be added more than once?

Comment: If you need to inhibit the pager, add `-c pager.log=false`: `git -c pager.log=false log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aD -1 -- <fname>`.

Comment: @mjs, yes, a file can be added more than once. For example, it can be added, then be removed, then be added again (I updated the answer).

Comment: @ruvim Using `--reverse` / `head` gives no results for some files. The first command works.

Comment: @AaronMahan It turns out that it is a bug in Git and it was already reported. The answer is updated accordingly.

Comment: git has a `--no-pager` options, so you can leave off the `| tail -1` (which also makes it easier to work with xargs)

Comment: @JohnBachir, Git uses a pager when the output is going to a terminal only. `| tail -1` is needed to take the last line only. It nothing to do with a pager.

Comment: @ruvim I see. Hm, here's the final code I used, which has files with lots of moves and commits, and worked correctly (I think), providing one date per file `ls -1 | xargs -n 1 git --no-pager log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aI --`. git 2.17.0

Comment: I'm extracting creation date for 30k files, this takes 5 hours. Halfway through I encountered 2 files, where `--diff-filter=A --follow` would yield no output. This seems to be files where the latest commit had a merge conflict.