# Automatic creation and committing of a file whenever I'm creating a certain type of file

Tags: bash, git, git-commit

I want to create an automatic script that will be part of the commit,
This script will add to a ceratin file line that say the file x was created.
For example: If I'm creating a file a.txt than it will automatically add to the commmit in file b.txt the line: "a.txt was created".

Comment: you have to add this to the precommit file. you can do as scprit that calls `git status --short` and gets the lines that start by "A" and copies them into your file

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without the precommit plugin?

Comment: Pinging this question

Comment: Are you looking for [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)?

Comment: @BarYaron as mentioned, I'm not talking about a "pluging" , but a git hooks

Comment: This is possible, I just want to say that this files doesn't sounds useful as you can get the information with git commands [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390382/11261546)